# Preparing data for Gephi

Tags: r, reshape, gephi, network-analysis

Greeting,

I would need to prepare data for network analysis in Gephi. I have data in the following format:

[MY Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG7bD.png)

And I need data in format (Where the values represent persons that are connected through the organization):

[Required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we0yV.png)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code should do the job. It is not the best most elegant way of doing it, but it works :)

```r
# Data
x <-
  structure(
    list(
      Persons = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      Organizations = c("A", "B", "E", "F", "A", "E", "C", "D", "C", "A", "E")
    ),
    .Names = c("Persons", "Organizations"),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -11L)
  )

# This will merge n:n
edgelist <- merge(x, x, by = "Organizations")[,2:3]

# We don't want autolinks
edgelist <- subset(edgelist, Persons.x != Persons.y)

# Removing those that are repeated
edgelist <- unique(edgelist)

edgelist
#>   Persons.x Persons.y
#> 2         1         3
#> 3         1         2
#> 4         3         1
#> 6         3         2
#> 7         2         1
#> 8         2         3
```

HIH

Created on 2018-01-03 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `x`:

```
structure(list(Persons = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Organizations = c("A", "B", "E", "F", "A", "E", "C", "D", "C", "A", "E")), .Names = c("Persons", "Organizations"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-11L))
```

Create a new `data.frame` with different names. Just convert `Organizations` to a factor and then use the numeric values:

```
> y=data.frame(Source=x$Persons, Target=as.numeric(as.factor(x$Organizations)))
> y
   Source Target
1       1      1
2       1      2
3       1      5
4       2      6
5       2      1
6       2      5
7       2      3
8       3      4
9       3      3
10      3      1
11      3      5
```

For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure gephi can handle strings.